# How to change JsRender template tags?

Tags: jsrender, jsviews

I use Twig. It uses these tags: `{{ name }}`

I want to include JsRender in my project. But JsRender also uses the same tags `{{:name}}`, so there is a conflict and nothing works. How to change default JsRender tags with custom tags, say Ruby-like `<%= name %>`

**UPD:**

For some reason I cannot make it work with control flow tags, `for` doesn't behave as expected with custom tags. Why does it happen?

Here is a template:

```
<script id="myTmpl" type="text/x-jsrender">
    <%!-- This is a copmment %>
    <% for data %>
        <%:key%>
    <% /for %>
</script>
```

Here is `js` code:

```
var template = $.templates("#myTmpl");
var htmlOutput = template.render(data);
$(".div").html(htmlOutput);
```

Here is a rendered result:

```
<%!-- This is a copmment %> <% for data %> <% /for %>
```

Comment: You added some incorrect whitespace in your tags. See working snippet in answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JsRender let's you change the delimiters, like this:

```
$.views.settings.delimiters("<%", "%>");
```

So then you would write `<%: name %>`.

If you use JsViews, you can also set the binding character `^` in `{^{` - by writing:

```
$.views.settings.delimiters("<%", "%>", "*");
```

then using `<*%: name %>`.

***Example*** (runs as snippet below):

```
<%!-- a comment --%>

<%:title%>
<%for items%>
    <div><%:name %></div>
<%/for%>
```

```js
$.views.settings.delimiters("<%", "%>");

var data = {
  title:"The Title",
  items: [
 {name:"Item one"},
  {name:"Item two"}
 ]
};

var template = $.templates("#myTmpl");

var htmlOutput = template.render(data);

$("#result").html(htmlOutput);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//www.jsviews.com/download/jsrender.js"></script>

<script id="myTmpl" type="text/x-jsrender">
<%!-- a comment --%>
<%:title%>
<%for items%>
 <div><%:name %></div>
<%/for%>
</script>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Note that you must simply replace the original `"{{"` and `"}}"`characters by the chosen replacement ones, but not change the whitespace. After replacement, `<% for items%>` would be incorrect, since the correct syntax is `{{for items}}`, not `{{ for items}}`. (That was your error above...). It should be `<%for items%>`. etc.

See [Setting tag delimiters for JsRender](http://www.jsviews.com/#settings/delimiters) for documentation.

See http://www.jsviews.com/#jsrtags for tag syntax.

Comment: It seems it works for the data path or expression tags but doesn't work for `for` tag and as I suspect it doesn't work for other control flow tags like `for` - `if`,`else`, etc. It doesn't work for comment tag for sure. How to use all other tags? Control flow tags. Please see update for my question.

Comment: Well clearly you need to follow the JsRender syntax. Start with a working template, then substitute the characters. It is {{for ...}}...{{/for}}, not {{ for ... }}...{{ /for }}.