# both front- and back-end template engines

Tags: templates, jinja2, template-engine, jsrender

I have a python program that uses Jinja2 template engine to render html pages on back-end. I have a task to migrate the major part of data rendering to JsRender engine(to process it on front-end). But being in same file they conflict.

How does one use both front- and back-end template engines together? Could you give please some examples?

Comment: also you can use {% raw %} in Jinja2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your issue is with Jinja2 and JsRender both using `{{...}}` delimiters.

You can choose to use different delimiters in JsRender. See [Setting tag delimiters for JsRender](http://www.jsviews.com/#settings/delimiters) for documentation.

See also the equivalent question which was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29497325/1054484